# How to access front/back camera using java (webcam-capture)

Tags: java, webcam-capture

I am using this java library to access camera in laptop/pc. [Webcam-capture](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/)

```
Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
webcam.open();
ImageIO.write(webcam.getImage(), "PNG", new File(path));
```

Above code giving me back camera streaming, i want to switch both front/back cameras programatically.

I am following this [Webcam-capture Guide](http://webcam-capture.sarxos.pl/) but unable to find any related documentation for switching cameras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebCam.getWebcams()` returns a list of available Webcams which you can iterate and use, instead of using the one `getDefault()` returns.